# Reading Spaces Between Longs

Tags: java, swing, spaces

The problem here lies in the JButton "AddEmployee".

The long's phone number and social security I.D. don't show the spaces in the text file.

```
JButton btnAddEmployee = new JButton("Add Employee");
        btnAddEmployee.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                try{
                    String name = txtName.getText();
                    String address = txtAddress.getText();
                    double pay = Double.parseDouble(txtPay.getText());
                    long ssid = Long.parseLong(txtSSID.getText());
                    long number = Long.parseLong(txtNumber.getText());
                    FinalProjectGroup1 ee = new FinalProjectGroup1(name, address, pay, ssid, number);
                    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(txtFolder.getText(), true);
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
                    pw.println(ee.getName() + ", " + ee.getAddress() + ", " + ee.getNumber()
                    + ", " + ee.getPay() + ", " + ee.getSSID());
                    pw.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Question edited to allow code formatting to show. Also I've removed the [tag:eclipse] tag as the question appears to have nothing to do with an Eclipse problem.

Comment: Give us some examples.

Comment: There is ar too much code here. You should reduce this to just the code required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Phone numbers and SSN's should not be handled as numbers, period, since they really aren't treated as numbers. Do you ever do addition with a phone number? Division with a SSN? Handle them as Strings and your problems may be fixed.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't use `null` layouts. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern UI design, you have no control over fonts, DPI, rendering pipelines or other factors that will change the way that you components will be rendered on the screen. Swing was designed to work with layout managers to overcome these issues. If you insist on ignoring these features and work against the API design, be prepared for a lot of headaches and never ending hard work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One major issue I see is that you're trying to handle phone numbers and social security numbers as if they were *numbers*, longs to be exact, and in fact they are not. While they are comprised of numeric characters, you never would consider doing numeric operations on them such as addition, subtraction, or multiplication. Handle them always as Strings.

---

**Edit**
Also, as alerted by MadProgrammer, never ignore exceptions as you're doing here:

```
try
{
    String name = txtName.getText();
    String address = txtAddress.getText();
    double pay = Double.parseDouble(txtPay.getText());
    long ssid = Long.parseLong(txtSSID.getText());
    long number = Long.parseLong(txtNumber.getText());
    FinalProjectGroup1 ee = new FinalProjectGroup1(name, address, pay, ssid, number);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(txtFolder.getText(), true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
    pw.println(ee.getName() + ", " + ee.getAddress() + ", " + ee.getNumber()
    + ", " + ee.getPay() + ", " + ee.getSSID());
    pw.close();
}

catch (Exception e)
{
    return;
}
```

At the very least, print the stacktrace so that you know what bad things might be happening:

```
try
{
    String name = txtName.getText();
    String address = txtAddress.getText();
    double pay = Double.parseDouble(txtPay.getText());
    long ssid = Long.parseLong(txtSSID.getText());
    long number = Long.parseLong(txtNumber.getText());
    FinalProjectGroup1 ee = new FinalProjectGroup1(name, address, pay, ssid, number);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(txtFolder.getText(), true);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
    pw.println(ee.getName() + ", " + ee.getAddress() + ", " + ee.getNumber()
    + ", " + ee.getPay() + ", " + ee.getSSID());
    pw.close();
}

catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you also add the fact that the OP is throwing away the `Exception` would have alert them to this issue

Comment: I again apologize for any inconvenience I may have caused for my original post before my editing. As I've stated before I do not know programming, I am new and I am not familiar with any terms you may throw at me. In my class I've felt that I've not learned anything besides what I know I know, if that makes sense. So much so that I can say I did not know what a long was, nor did I know that it specifically dealt with arithmetic. I again apologize for my being new here, seeing as that only gets me negative, "Are you an idiot" responses. Thank you for your time and trouble.

Comment: @WahtsUpWorld: don't be too hard on yourself, and please don't beat yourself up -- that's our job. Seriously though, you'll get better at Java with practice, and your questions will get better too. Your first one above wasn't a bad one, other than throwing perhaps a bit too much code at us, but knowing what is too much code and what is too little takes experience. Keep at it, persevere, and you may soon find that you actually like this stuff.